# Upload Firebase Data In Table Cell

Tags: ios, firebase, swift3, firebase-realtime-database

I have created the below function in ViewController.swift and want to pass the info that's stored inside the dictionary to a cell in TableViewConntroller.swift. I referenced [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tv5c1mZttVE), but data isn't being loaded. I have also checked out other resources that have similar solutions, but nothing is shown. Not sure what I have to do in order to have the data that is saved appear inside the cell.

```
func addUserData() {

let key = refUsers?.childByAutoId().key

let user = ["id": key!, "firstName": firstNameField.text! as String, "limits": limitationsField.text! as String, "city": citystateField.text! as String]

refUsers.child(key!).setValue(user) }
```

Comment: You should first read that data, and then reload your table view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check out this link:

[READ/RETRIVING DATA FROM FIREBASE DATABASE to NSDICTIONARY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43858957/reading-retrieving-data-from-firebase)

There you get data as NSDICTIONARY and then you can play around to put on the TableView cell.